# Manipulação de itens durante iteração

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, variáveis

No Python é um tanto quanto comum percorrer itens de um **iterável** manuseando ou verificando a existência de determinado item, ou qualquer que seja a operação. estou lendo novamente a documentação do Python e me deparo com algo que quando visto pela primeira vez não acreditei ser algo digamos relevante.
Por exemplo:

```
>>> animals = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Elephant']
>>> for animal in animals:
...     print(animal, len(animal))

Cat 3
Dog 3
Elephant 8
```

Como podem ver itero sobre uma lista contendo nomes de animais e imprimo o animal atual no laço, assim como a quantidade de caracteres do mesmo. A única operação que faço neste exemplo é a impressão dos seus nome e a quantidade de caracteres, não tento de forma alguma alterar o valor dos mesmos. Minha dúvida exatamente quando penso em alterar esses valores.

```
>>> animals = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Elephant']
>>> for animal in animals:
...     if len(animal) > 3:
            animal = animal[:3]
        print(animal, len(animal))

Cat 3
Dog 3
Ele 3

>>> print(animals)
```

A saída dentro do laço como podem ver demonstra que a variável no laço foi alterada, mas ao imprimir a lista depois do laço vejo que a lista em si não foi. Isso me deixou perplexo, pois sinceramente o que estou mostrando aqui como exemplos não passam de coisas que me vieram a mente que acredito que todos já pensamos em fazer que é alterar uma variável durante um laço de repetição, outro fato é que estudando o Python aprendemos que alguns de seus tipos mais básicos como `string`, `int`, `float` e até as `tuplas` são imutáveis, ou seja, porque a reatribuição na variável atual do laço não gerou uma nova *string* (no caso uma *string* de três caracteres), pensando dessa forma pensei em verificar se a variável 
no laço atual era o a mesma da lista sendo iterado, da seguinte forma:

```
>>> animals = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Elephant']
>>> for animal in animals:
...     print(animal, id(animal))

Cat 140226536948264
Dog 140226536948040
Elephant 140226536875248

>>> animals[0], id(animals[0])
Cat 140226536948264
>>> animals[1], id(animals[1])
Dog 140226536948040
>>> animals[2], id(animals[2])
Elephant 140226536875248
```

Perceberam? São os mesmos identificadores. Não sei em outras linguagens mas na documentação do Python é descrito que deve-se criar uma cópia do iterável antes do laço visto que o mesmo não faz isso implicitamente, mas minha dúvida ainda é essa porque não posso alterar o item atual do laço `for`.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o seu exemplo. Aqui mostrou tamanho 3 para todos, como você esperava: https://repl.it/repls/StrikingIllustriousNumbers

Comment: Durante a iteração o item é alterado de forma a ficar com 3 caracteres mas após a iteração a lista em si está inalterada.

Comment: Sim, mas não é isso que está na sua pergunta. Você alterou a variável e a exibiu dentro do laço. Pelo seu texto, você perguntou porque `animal` continuou sendo `Elephant` dentro do laço mesmo atribuindo `animal = animal[:3]`. Se a intenção era perguntar sobre porque a alteração não é refletida na lista original, acho que precisa reformular a pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe se não ficou claro alterei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta ficou um pouco confusa porque não é possível reproduzir o resultado. Parece que era isto que queria demonstrar:

```
animals = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Elephant']
for animal in animals:
    print(animal, id(animal))
for animal in animals:
    if len(animal) > 3:
        animal = animal[:3]
    print(animal, len(animal), id(animal))
for animal in animals:
    print(animal, len(animal), id(animal))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ENgnfW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vxdnbgtt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/LoopCow.py).

Note que mostrei primeiro os endereços de cada item, depois mostrei os itens mostrando o `id` com indicação quando ele muda, e novamente os `id`s indicando que a lista está intacta. Quando você vai fazer uma prova tem que ter um controle, mostrar o fenômeno ocorrendo e depois o estado de tudo, senão pode ter ilusões.

E a dúvida parece ser porque a lista não foi alterada. A pergunta foi alterada em um detalhe do texto, mas todo o resto ainda dá o entendimento errado do que desejava.

A variável do laço não é o que você está pensando. Ela não tem o valor do item e sim uma referência **imutável** para um item da coleção de dados que está varrendo no laço. Então você não tem permissão para alterar o dado na coleção. Você acha que tem uma variável que carrega um valor isolado. Mas não é isso até que você tente escrever nela. Aí há o que se chama de COW (Copy On Write) e uma nova referência é criada e alocada na variável, apontando para um novo local na memória onde o valor do elemento é copiado e para sua própria proteção ele não deixa você mudar este valor na lista.

Em um laço direto não haveria esta proteção. O padrão de projeto `foreach` comum em várias linguagens existe para facilitar a iteração de itens de forma segura. Se precisa da flexibilidade e destrave a segurança usando um laço bruto.

Observe que o `id` antes do *loop* no terceiro item é um, e dentro dele quando há alteração é outro. Portanto seu teste não analisou corretamente e lhe deu uma informação falsa. A variável `animal` quando é mudada tem outro valor. Quando não é mudada por otimização não precisa ter outro valor.

Acho que o conceito fundamental aqui é o COW, ele causou a ilusão e o teste original não possibilitou ele ser observado. É comum em todas linguagens tipos por valor serem imutáveis e utilizarem o COW para otimizar o acesso. Tipos por referência não costumam ser imutáveis e aí não faz sentido ter o COW, por isso um tipo assim permitiria que você mudasse seu valor. Note que a *string* até é um tipo por referência por otimização, mas tem semântica de valor, por isso é imutável e segue o mesmo critério.

Comment: A atribuição da variável intermediária do loop funciona como uma atribuição normal; portanto, é imutável só pra objetos imutáveis. Iterar sobre uma lista de listas por exemplo permite a modificação dos elementos (já que a variável intermediária aponta pra lista por referência, como esperado).

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig deixei isso mais claro na resposta, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

[Essa seção da documentação tem a informação relevante](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

O que acontece de fato não é muito intuitivo, mas é facilmente explicável. Ao iterar sobre uma lista, cada item é atribuído, um por vez, a uma variável intermediária do loop, uma referência ao objeto do iterável.

Quer dizer, isso:

```
minha_lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in minha_lista:
    if item == 2:
        item = 10
print(minha_lista)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

É na verdade o equivalente a isso:

```
minha_lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in range(len(minha_lista)):
    item = minha_lista[i]
    if item == 2:
        item = 10
print(minha_lista)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Percebe a diferença? Quando fazemos uma atribuição a essa variável intermediária, estamos na verdade mudando a referência da variável, e não o item original na lista. **Isso pra tipos imutáveis.**

A atribuição a essa variável intermediária funciona do mesmo jeito que uma atribuição normal. Quer dizer, se iterarmos sobre uma lista de listas, por exemplo, a variável apontará para a referência (e não o valor) de cada uma dessas listas. Podemos observar que o seguinte se comporta de modo diferente:

```
lista_de_listas = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

for item in lista_de_listas:
    if item == [1, 2, 3]:
        item[1] = 10
print(lista_de_listas)
# [[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

---

Um modo de contornar essa dificuldade pra quando se está lidando com objetos imutáveis é de acessar a lista diretamente. Pode se fazer isso sem perder a conveniência de ter uma variável intermediária com o `enumerate`:

```
minha_lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, item in enumerate(minha_lista):
    if item == 2:
        minha_lista[i] = 10
print(minha_lista)
# [1, 10, 3, 4, 5]
```